# How can i put custom fields on Standard SalesForce object, with PHP, using metadata API

Tags: php, metadata, salesforce, custom-fields

I searched a couple of days and didn't find how can i put my custom fields in standard SalesForce object (Account, Lead, Opportunity etc...).
 I found only info about metadata API described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf), but it explains inserting new metadata only on custom objets. I found [this code](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Metadata_Create_Sample) too, but it works only for custom objects too. Does anybody knows more about this stuff? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here is final working code for those who can't find example.

```
// SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR - folder that contains the PHP Toolkit and your WSDL
// $USERNAME - variable that contains your Salesforce.com username (must be in the form of an email)
// $PASSWORD - variable that contains your Salesforce.com password
define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceMetadataClient.php');
require_once ('../userAuth.php');
try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
  $loginResult = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
  $myMetadataConnection = new SforceMetadataClient(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/metadata.wsdl.xml', $loginResult, $mySforceConnection);
  $customField = new SforceCustomField();
  $customField->setFullName('Account.MyCustomFieldb__c');
  $customField->setDescription('Description of New Field');
  $customField->setLabel('My Custom Field Label');
  $customField->setType('Text');
  $customField->setLength(255);
  print_r($myMetadataConnection->create($customField));
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $myMetadataConnection->getLastRequest();
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would create populate a [CustomField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/customfield.htm) structure, setting the fullName property based on the standard object you want to add it to, e.g. Account.rating__c and then pass that to the [create](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_create.htm) metadata API call. I don't know about PHP, bu there's an example in .NET [here](http://www.pocketsoap.com/weblog/2008/05/1811.html).

Comment: I tried it but it rises an Error "The custom object name must finish with __c".

Comment: Sounds like you're sending a CustomObject and not just a CustomField.